# Kafka Streams creates avro topic without schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I developed a java application which reads data from an avro topic, using Schema Registry, then makes simple transformations and prints the result in the console. By default I used GenericAvroSerde class for keys and values. Everything worked fine except that I had to define additionally configuration for each serde like

```
    final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url", kafkaStreamsConfig.getProperty("schema.registry.url"));
    final Serde<GenericRecord> keyGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
    final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
    keyGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true);
    valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
```

Without that I always get an error like:

```
Exception in thread "NTB27821-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to deserialize value for record. topic=CH-PGP-LP2_S20-002_agg, partition=0, offset=4482940
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.deserialize(SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.java:46)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:84)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:117)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:474)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:642)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:548)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:519)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 69
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:122)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:93)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroDeserializer.deserialize(GenericAvroDeserializer.java:63)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroDeserializer.deserialize(GenericAvroDeserializer.java:39)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.deserialize(SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:474)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:642)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:548)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:519)
```

Well, it was unsual, but fine, after that (when I added configuration call as I posted above) - it worked and my application was able to to all the operations and print out the result.

But!
When I tried to use call through() - just to post data to the new topic - I faced the problem I am asking about: TOPIC WAS CREATED WITHOUT A SCHEMA.
How it can be???

Interesting fact is that the data is being written, but it is:
a) in binary format, so simple consumer cannot read it
b) it has not a schema - so avro consumer can't read it either:

```
    Processed a total of 1 messages
[2017-10-05 11:25:53,241] ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$:105)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 0
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:182)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:203)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:379)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:372)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:65)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:131)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:122)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:93)
        at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageFormatter.writeTo(AvroMessageFormatter.java:122)
        at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageFormatter.writeTo(AvroMessageFormatter.java:114)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.process(ConsoleConsumer.scala:140)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:78)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:53)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
[2017-10-05 11:25:53,241] ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$:105)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 0
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:182)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:203)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:379)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:372)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:65)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:131)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:122)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:93)
        at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageFormatter.writeTo(AvroMessageFormatter.java:122)
        at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageFormatter.writeTo(AvroMessageFormatter.java:114)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.process(ConsoleConsumer.scala:140)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:78)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:53)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

Of course I checked out the schema registry for the subject:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects/agg_value_9-value/versions
{"error_code":40401,"message":"Subject not found."}
```

But the same call to another topic written by Java App - producer of the initial data shows that schema exist:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects/CH-PGP-LP2_S20-002_agg-value/versions
[1]
```

Both applications use identical "schema.registry.url" configuration
Just to summarize - topic is created, data is written, can be read with simple consumer, but it is binary and the schema doesn't exist.

Also I tried to create a schema with a Landoop, somehow to match the data, but no success - and by the way it is not a proper way to use kafka streams - everything should be done on the fly.

Help, please!

Comment: Which version do you use? Also, so you set AvroSerde in `StreamsConfig` as default or do you set on each operator individually? Did you create the topic uses in through manually and before you start your application? Also check out this example: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/3.3.0-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/GenericAvroIntegrationTest.java#L83-L85

Comment: I use Confluent 3.3.0, java 1.8, kafka 0.11.0.0-cp1, avro version 1.7.7. I set GenericAvroSerde as default, but for simple types case by case I override these settings (Serdes.Long, Serdes.String, Serdes.Float). The topic I intend to use didn't exist, but it was created while the data was written as I wrote in starting post.

Comment: And regarding the example - I do all the same, except that in the example key is decoded as a bytearray while I use stringSerde for that (because avro schema for the key is just "string").  Schema regstry url is available, if it wasn't I wouldn't be able to read the initial data in the kafka streams app. But I am able and the final stream is printed correctly when I do just finalStream.print()

Comment: If you set avro as default in StreamsConfig, I am wondering why you need to call `configure` (ie, the whole first code block in you question). Streams will configure your Serde automatically -- if not, your setup seems not to be correct. Can you maybe share your StreamsConfig code? Did you have a look into the example I shared?

Answer (score 0):

When `through` is called, the default serde defined via `StreamsConfig` is used unless users specifically overrides it. Which default serde did you use? To be correct you should be using the AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer which will automatically register the schema for that through topic.